# What happens to the old state when a new state is emitted in flutter bloc?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

What happens to an old state when a new state is emitted? Does the flutter bloc hold a reference to the old state or is it garbage collected by dart?

Answer (score 1):

In vanilla `bloc`s there previous state reference is no longer is used so eventually is garbage collected by the Dart VM.

Take a look at [`BlocBase.emit`](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/master/packages/bloc/lib/src/bloc_base.dart#L92-L106) method. The `onChange` method is called and then the current state (`_state = state`) is updated to the stated passed in your `emit`.

```dart
void emit(State state) {
  try {
    if (isClosed) {
      throw StateError('Cannot emit new states after calling close');
    }
    if (state == _state && _emitted) return;
    onChange(Change<State>(currentState: this.state, nextState: state));
    _state = state;
    _stateController.add(_state);
    _emitted = true;
  } catch (error, stackTrace) {
    onError(error, stackTrace);
    rethrow;
  }
}
```